# What is the difference between residue and remainder?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the difference between residue and remainder?

I think that the remainder can be negative but residue is always non-negative. Am I correct?

Comment: In polynomial division, negative remainders are certainly common; in integer division, a negative remainder is probably (at best) frowned upon...

Comment: wilson's theorem states$(p-1)!\equiv -1 (mod \space  p)$hence, residues can be negative

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at a really simple example where we divide $\color{#00c}{11}$ by $\color{#0a0}{4}$:

> We write $\color{#00c}{11}=\color{#0a0}4*2+\color{#c00}{3}$, where $\color{#c00}3$ is called the "remainder."

We can easily rewrite this equation in modular form as $\color{#00c}{11} \equiv \color{#c00}3 \bmod \color{#0a0}4$, where $\color{#c00}3$ is called the "residue."

Keep in mind we can also write $\color{#00c}{11} \equiv \color{#c00}{-1} \mod \color{#0a0}4$, where $\color{#c00}{-1}$ is also the residue. A residue can certainly be negative.

So, in reality, the "remainder" and the "residue" are the exact same, but are each used in their respective fields:

> Division $\implies$ "Remainder"
> Modular $\implies$ "Residue"